# Problem With MapBox iOS MGLPolyline when crossing the (180 or -180) Longitude

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

in MapBox iOS sdk 4.4.1 if the MGLPolyline crosses the (180 or -180) Longitude , the map shows that it is going the longer way around the globe instead of going the shorter way.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let points = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.0, longitude: -170.0),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.0, longitude: 170),
                ]
    let line = MGLPolyline(coordinates: points, count: UInt(points.count))
    line.title = "line"
    mapView.addAnnotation(line)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that consecutive points are joined along lines of increasing latitude and/or longitude but default. Mapbox’s info regarding how to overcome this for MGLPolyline is found here.

The part of interest is: [Mapbox MGLPolyline link](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/Classes/MGLPolyline.html)

> To make the polyline go across the antimeridian or international date line, specify some longitudes less than −180 degrees or greater than 180 degrees. For example, a polyline that stretches from Tokyo to San Francisco would have coordinates of (35.68476, -220.24257) and (37.78428, -122.41310).

So they're leaving it to the developer to implement their own logic to decide when and if it is appropriate to go the longer or shorter route.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,  the problem that I am working on a project which has many great circle functions , which only accept longitude in the range of [180,-180] and also the result would be in the same range , and trying to change those functions would be a very long and impractical , is there anything else I CAN DO ?

Comment: @user3556225 Just a suggestion: I wouldn't alter any great circle functions. I'd create a post-processing translation function that converts the results to something the Mapbox SDK can display properly.