# MapBox: How to plot a line across world maps

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

If a line needs to be plotted between Mexico to Japan, i want the line to be directed or plotted between two maps across pacific ocean rather than across EU and Asia continent.

How to achieve such a behaviour?

```
 MapA           MapB
Mexico  ->      Japan
```

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584818/problem-with-mapbox-ios-mglpolyline-when-crossing-the-180-or-180-longitude/52586346#52586346

Answer (score 0):

Draw it in segments that are broken at the date line?

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive.